# Yarn resolution for a package with multiple versions

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

My application has a vulnerability with a package that has multiple versions ongoing (1.x, 2.x, 3.x). There are a lot of packages I use that use the latter one as a dependency, so updating one by one is not feasible right now. I would use `yarn resolutions`, but some have the package as dependency with version 1.x and others have 2.x. If I force a 2.x resolution, this would probably break the ones using 1.x

Is there any way to make yarn resolutions support one with multiple versions? Something like:

```
"resolutions": {
 "foo": "~1.0.5 || ~2.0.5",
}
```

Otherwise, what options do I have?

Comment: How would your app know which of the versions to use when it's included both?

Comment: @Cerbrus I know, it's a long stretch, but maybe yarn has some sort of mechanism to assign a resolution with multiple versions depending on a major version number or similar :/

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve specifically when the dependency is a sub-dependency of certain packages; assuming you are using Yarn 1, this is an example from the [official docs](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/#toc-how-to-use-it)

```json
  "resolutions": {
    "d2/left-pad": "1.1.1",
    "c/**/left-pad": "^1.1.2"
  }
```

However, you should be able to target these to be the different major version numbers you want